# Text input for multi-valued attribute

Tags: java, jsf

I need to create an input form that will allow a user to enter any number of values for a particular attribute.

I've tried several approaches, all of which seem to have various levels of failure.  The latest model bean looks something like:

```
public class Product {
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList(5);

  {
    tags.add("");  //seed with 1 non-null element
  }

  ...accessors...
}
```

The input fields look something like:

```
    <h:dataTable id="tags" value="#{product.tags}" var="tag">
      <h:column><h:inputText id="t" value="#{tag}"></h:inputText></h:column>
```

My plan was to allow the user is to use javascript to add additional form fields as needed.

<del>This type of setup gives me a 'Target Unreachable' error.  What am I missing?</del>

My problem now is that the setter for tags does not get called.  Oddly enough, the setter for name does.

I am using JSF 1.1 on WebSphere 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preinstantiate/preserve any non-standard objects yourself. EL won't preinstantiate them for you. This applies on anything else than `String`, `Number` and `Boolean` for which EL has built-in recognizions and coercions. No, arrays like `String[]` are not covered as you encountered.

Basically the following should do:

```
private String[] tags = new String[length];
```

You'll only need to pass the `length` as a `<input type="hidden" name="length">` and let JS fill it, <strike>so that you can preserve the object in a `@PostConstruct` yourself:</strike>

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.length}")
private int length;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.tags = new String[length];
}
```

**Update:** Sorry, the above applies on JSF 1.2 or newer only. Well, in your case you'll have to do some hacky works such as grabbing it from `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`. Please also keep in mind that JavaScript doesn't see anything from the JSF source code, it instead only sees its generated HTML output. Rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source*. Take this into account when coding JS.

Comment: BalusC, with your help i've been able to get a bit farther.  However, I'm encountering a new issue.  I've removed the logic to support adding the text fields through JS, the only thing left figuring out why the managed view isn't being updated with the form.  I've updated accordingly above.

Comment: Long story short: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#AddNewRowsToDatatable

Comment: that section makes sense, however i'm still unable to get setTags in managed bean to execute (setName executes).  I don't see any exceptions in the logs; and the request does contain what i typed in for a tag.  

my understanding of the jsf request life cycle would be that the view is first restored (execute gets in managed bean) then the request values are applied (execute the sets). i feel like i am missing something, but don't know what.

the rendered input tag looks like:

<input id="new:tags:0:tag" type="text" name="new:tags:0:tag" value="ball" />

Comment: I don't recall if a `List<String>` would work in JSF 1.1, but I'd give `List<RowObject>` a shot. Further it's good to know that setters are never called for collections or nested model objects. JSF will basically do `bean.getList().get(rowIndex).setSomeProperty(requestParameterValue)`.

Comment: BalusC, that did the trick.  Create an object for a tag (which is what I would need to end up doing).

Thanks for the info on the fact setters aren't called for collections or nested model objects.  i don't recall reading that anywhere.

Comment: misclick, but i can't seem to upvote it again without you editing the response...can you edit and i can re-upvote?